# Show that $\left(\frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2^n}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ is a null sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $\left(\frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2^n}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ is a null sequence. A null sequence is a sequence tending to $0$.

We need to find a $N\in \mathbb{N}$ for every $\varepsilon >0$, such that $n\geq N:|a_n-0|<\varepsilon$.

Usually, I first try to simplify the argument, but that does not work, since we have $n$ as the exponent and as a base. Secondly, I'll try to achieve an inequality like $n>...$. Tis sadly doesn't work out aswell. This expression is way to hard to simplify.

Is there another method, an easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: $2^n>n^2$ for $n>4$, so ...

Comment: @robjohn huh?  $0<n^{3/2}/2^n<n^{3/2}/n^2=n^{-1/2}$ etc.

Comment: @user10354138: Sorry; I misread. I thought you were claiming that $2^n\gt n^\alpha\implies\frac{n^\alpha}{2^n}\to0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^n$ is exponential which grows faster than any power sequence. So at some point we must have $2^n>n^2$ (specifically $n\geq 4$ works), and so the sequence is now bounded above by $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$, which clearly tends to $0$.

Comment: But how does showing that $2^n>n^2$ imply that it is a null sequence? You also have $n+1\geqslant n$ for each $n$, but $\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not a null sequence...

Comment: It isn't just larger, the growth rate is higher too (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth#Other_growth_rates)

Comment: Hi again, how do you know that the sequence is now bounded above by $\frac 1 {\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic We have $\frac{n^\frac{3}{2}}{2^n} < \frac{n^\frac{3}{2}}{n^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: Ok, I really like that way since I have already proved that $2^n>n^2$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 4}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 1/2 $$ thus your sequence tends to zero.

Comment: What about: $\left(\frac{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}{2^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=0.5\cdot n^{\frac{3}{2n}}= ....$